# Migrate a production database to the same structure as a dev database

Tags: database, entity-framework-6, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-migrations

I have a SQL Server CE database on my 'live' host that I deployed a few weeks ago. It has a migration history of two old migrations. Then I have my dev database, that has gone through umpteen migrations, and several delete and recreate moments.

Now I would like to use EF migrations to build a migration that will update the production db to match my code-first model on dev. I thought that if I cleared the prod migration history, and ran `Add-Migration`, EF would compare database and model, and generate a migration class to bring the db up to date with the model.

What really happens is that the migration that gets generated tries to create the whole dd, well, all tables, FKs, and Indexes. How do I get a proper update only, using EF migrations?

Comment: You could use my schema diff script from the SQL CE Toolbox instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still have the deployed migration on your Dev box, you can create a script that will bring the deployed version up to date:

```
Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration: VersionDeployed -TargetMigration: CurrentMigration
```

You could also try bringing the PROD database down with the migration history (don't clear it). EF should compare the model in the last migration to the current model based on code.

http://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/#at_pco=smlwn-1.0&at_si=54ad5c7b61c48943&at_ab=per-12&at_pos=0&at_tot=1